# Sort response array in desc order in Java

Tags: java, arrays, json

I am trying to print the top 5 entries based on `total.amount` from an api response array.

The response looks something like this, but a lot longer:

```
[
    {
        "total": {
            "amount": "100000"
        },
        "name": {
            "first": "Test"
        },
    },
    {
        "total": {
            "amount": "500"
        },
        "name": {
            "first": "Test2"
        },
    }
]
```

At the moment I am able to print all the `amount` values in descending order:

```
public static void orderResultsDesc(int total) throws JSONException {
        JsonPath jsonPathValidator = response.jsonPath();
        List<String> totAm = jsonPathValidator.getList("total.amount");
        try {
            totAm.sort(Comparator.reverseOrder());
            System.out.println("List:\n" + totAm);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

But I need to adjust this to print the top 5 entries with a whole response (not just the `total.amount` values).

Have tried doing things like:

```
     List<Integer> ids = jsonPathValidator.getList("total.amount");
        for(Integer i:ids)
        {
            ids.sort(Comparator.reverseOrder());
            sortedOrder.add(ids); // this doesn't work
            System.out.println(i);
        }
```

It's new territory for me.. Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: 1) Create a list of Java objects from the JSON response. 2) Sort the list.

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach is to compute the indices of the five entries with the highest `"total.amount"`. A possible implementation using streams:

```java
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;


List<String> amounts = jsonPath.getList("total.amount");
List<Integer> indices = 
        // Create stream of indices (integers from 0 to items.size()-1)
        IntStream.range(0, amounts.size()).boxed()
        // Sort indices by decreasing amount
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(index -> Long.parseLong(amounts.get((int)index))).reversed())
        // We're only interested in the top five entries
        .limit(5)
        // Convert to list.
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

After that, you can iterate over these indices. To print the top five entries:

```java
for (int index : indices) {
    System.out.println(jsonPath.getString("[" + index + "]"));
}
```

Comment: ah that's of great help, thanks! After sorting the total.amount is there a way to print the whole response without doing "System.out.println("name.first=" + firstNames.get(index) + "; total.amount=" (...) ) ? As there are a lot of other objects aside from those two

Comment: Do you mean the whole JSON or only the five entries with the highest total.amount?

Comment: only the 5 entries

Comment: I've updated my response. The loop at the end now prints the five entries as JSON, but they will not be pretty-printed.

Comment: amazing.. saved the day, thanks mate!